# C# кодировка email

Tags: c#, email

Есть код:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Другие вопросы", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"), "text/plain");

    plainView.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;

    mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);

    mail.From = new MailAddress(from, name);
    //mail.To.Add("@.ru");
    mail.To.Add("@.ru");

    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");

    mail.Subject = "=?utf-8?B?Другие вопросы?=";
    mail.Body = text;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    //mail.SubjectEncoding

    if (att != "")
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(att));

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.local");
    smtpServer.Port = 25;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("@.ru", "password") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        return true;
    };

    try
    {
        smtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    Debug.Log("success");
    return true;
```

Как не бился от отправляет заголовок в QuotedPrintable для программы требуется Base64 Подскажите как правильно направить в нужное русло.

ПС. В коде присутуствует отладочная информация, не обращайте внимания

Comment: уточните, о каких заголовках речь; пытался разобраться в Вашем вопросе -- нашёл только заголовки [MailMessage.Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headers(v=vs.110).aspx); `AlternateView` вроде к заголовкам не имеет отношения.

Comment: mail.Subject получается на почту приходит заголовок в формате "=?utf-8?Q?Title?=" а необходим "=?utf-8?B?Title?="

Comment: Строка  mail.Subject = "=?utf-8?B?Другие вопросы?="; заставляет почтовик показать то какая кодировка приходит так как он сходит с ума из-за 2х кодировок

Comment: MailMessage сам энкодит `.Subject` при отправке. Попробуйте просто вписать "Другие вопросы" в  mail.Subject. Если не сработает - добавьте `message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`.

Comment: Именно так и было, это уже тестировал все варианты. при такой записи он энкодит и на почтовике тема имеет вид "=?utf-8?Q?......" хотя TransferEncoding указан как Base64